# Apache Ignite: TTL

Tags: java, ignite, ttl

Is it possible to set TTL on SQL rows in apache ignite?

I am aware of this documentation concerning TTL:
https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/expiry-policies but if I understand it right, it only applies to the cache layer?

What I need to do:

- Set TTL for a row upon insert
- Update TTL for single rows

It seems that the *ModifiedExpiryPolicy* is exactly what I need.

Is that possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is a limitation of API that you can't set expiry policy with SQL.

However, you can add rows using other mechanisms (Cache API, Data Streamer) and then use them across SQL.

Comment: Will the row be inserted into the SQL Table when i add it via the Cache API? Will it be automaticaly removed from the SQL DB when the TTL expires?